# Can't send Kafka messages though topic and producer both exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I'm working in TypeScript with the KafkaJS library locally, with a single kafka broker.  I've connected a producer successfully, have verified that my topic was created, and am generating messages with:

```
  const changeMessage = {
    key: id,
    value: JSON.stringify(person),
    headers: {
      changeType: status,
    },
  };
```

Now when I go to send the message:

```
  try {
    const sendResponse = await producer.send({
      topic: topicName2,
      messages: [changeMessage],
    });
    log.responseFragment(
      { id, topicName2 },
      `Sending changed/added person ${id} to topic ${topicName2}`
    );
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(
    { error }, `Could not send personChangedAdded ${id} to topic ${topicName2}`
    );
  }
```

Here's the error that I get back:

```
Could not send personChange to topic topicName2
    error: {
      "name": "KafkaJSError",
      "retriable": true
    }
```

Comment: Are there no more details in the error you can get other than your custom message (which doesn't match the code)? Do the broker logs show anything useful?

Comment: The error does not match that piece of code. i.e. `personChangedAdded` shows in the error handler with an id, but the error show something entirely different.

Comment: I can manually send messages using the CLI and a listener can pick them up, so it's definitely something I'm doing wrong with KafkaJS

Comment: @OneCricketeer From inside the broker in a listener, I'm getting Received unknown topic or partition error in fetch for partition topicName2-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher) and from the logs it's [2021-08-17 16:02:15,753] TRACE [Controller id=1 epoch=1] Received response StopReplicaResponseData(errorCode=0, partitionErrors=[StopReplicaPartitionError(topicName='IndividualEvents', partitionIndex=0, errorCode=0), StopReplicaPartition

Comment: Logs with `topicName='IndividualEvents'` are unrelated to your code unless that is actually your topic name. Please show where you set the value of `topicName2`

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, it turns out the problem was the `log.responseFragment` bit, and when we corrected it to `log.info` it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had failed to define `log.responseFragment()`, and when I changed it to a simple `log.info()` the problem was resolved.